# Nginx throws 404 only on php scripts using php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I've installed a testing server using `nginx` + `php-fpm`. I've tried all of the following:

[Nginx + Php5-fpm not rendering php files](https://serverfault.com/questions/213233/nginx-php5-fpm-not-rendering-php-files)

[nginx + php fpm -> 404 php pages - file not found](https://serverfault.com/questions/547393/nginx-php-fpm-404-php-pages-file-not-found)

[When accessing PHP files, nginx throws an 404 error](https://serverfault.com/questions/317231/when-accessing-php-files-nginx-throws-an-404-error)

Summarizing what I've tried:

- Reinstalling.
- Changing the script privileges (changed them to `0777`).
- `fastcgi_intercept_errors on`.
- Checked the `root` directive at the levels: `server`, `location` and `location ~ \.php`.
- Checked the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` directive.

The server returns 404 on (and only on) `.php` scripts. I can rename them to `.html` and they'd be fine. How can I go about this?

This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  2;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /var/www/html;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
            #root /var/www/html;
        }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            #root /var/www/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved it. It turns out that the problem was the permissions set on the socket where php was listening. I just had to change a directive called `listen.mode` on `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
listen.mode = 0750
```

And set the user to `nginx`:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
```

So the file looks like this:

```
srwxr-x---. 1 nginx nginx 0 jul  8 08:59 /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Because I was using a unix socket instead of a tcp port:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Also, I was getting `404` instead of `500` or `503` because my `www.conf` was configured to *redirect* errors to *custom pages*, and since they weren't there, I was getting `404`'s.

Edit:

It appears that in most recent versions of the nginx distribution in Fedora (Fedora 22, 23), nginx uses the apache user by default, and the socket is set to the user apache too, so no further configuration is needed.

Comment: Right, you must control: 
- What user/group run nginx (or any webserver)
- What user/group run php-fpm

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue, until I noticed my PHP location block was missing the `root` entry.

I had set one in the server block under `location /`, but not one on the server or inside the PHP location block.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                root /usr/local/www/; <--- this was missing
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php82-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
```

Or have one set one the server level

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com www.example.com;
        root   /usr/local/www/; <--- this line here
        location / {
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I Actually got a "Not Found" error because a book I read gave me an incorrect matching string for the path `/php_status` which I had configured in php-fpm 7.0.x (currently 7.0.19) and in nginx 1.12 (currently 1.12.0)

Here is the `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/{config}`

```
pm.status_path = /php_status
```

Here is the config for `default` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` (I'm on Ubuntu)

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  root /var/www;

  index index.html index.htm default.html;
  access_log /dev/null;
  error_log /dev/null;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location /php_status {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

> **Note:** The following is designed so that `/php_status` is not publicly available on the internet (nor is PHP served or setup for default host). It also includes `fastcgi_pass` directive for tcp and unix-socket php-fpm

You also should run the following two commands after

```
sudo service nginx reload
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

To verify try running

```
curl http://127.0.0.1/php_status
```

Answer (score -1):

It occured to me, for another reason:
The solution was to put this definition:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;  # <- replace with your directory
```

in the **server** block, NOT in the **location** block:

```
server {
    listen ....
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;  # <- replace with your directory
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # no 'root' definition here :)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: no, you can also set a location based root. it might be wrong for the specific location but not in general imho

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).